# How can I do array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, html-table

I have html table  with input. I want get value in inputbox

```html
<table id="yeni">
  <tr id="1">
    <td>
      <input id="1_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="1_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="1_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="1_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="1_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="1_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="1_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>
      <input id="2_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="2_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="2_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="2_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="2_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="2_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="2_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>
      <input id="3_1" style="width: 70px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="3_2" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="3_3" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="3_4" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="3_5" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="3_6" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="3_7" style="width: 80px; font-size: 11px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

for every row ı want to create object

```js
var stoktbl = {}
var table = [];

var rowCount = document.getElementById('yeni').rows.length;
for (var satirx = 1; satirx < rowCount; satirx++) {

  stoktbl.firma_barkod = document.getElementById(satirx + "_" + "1").value;
  stoktbl.adet = document.getElementById(satirx + "_" + "5").value;
  stoktbl.birim_satis_fiyati = document.getElementById(satirx + "_" + "6").value;

  table[satirx] = stoktbl;
}

var JsonString = JSON.stringify(table)
console.log(JsonString)
```

when run it with ;

I see  only last row data repaet  like

```js
[null, {
  "adet": "1",
  "birim_satis_fiyati": "69.9",
  "firma_barkod": "091986 "
}, {
  "adet": "1",
  "birim_satis_fiyati": "69.9",
  "firma_barkod": "091986 "
}, {
  "adet": "1",
  "birim_satis_fiyati": "69.9",
  "firma_barkod": "091986 "
}, {
  "adet": "1",
  "birim_satis_fiyati": "69.9",
  "firma_barkod": "091986 "
}, {
  "adet": "1",
  "birim_satis_fiyati": "69.9",
  "firma_barkod": "091986 "
}, {
  "adet": "1",
  "birim_satis_fiyati": "69.9",
  "firma_barkod": "091986 "
}, {
  "adet": "1",
  "birim_satis_fiyati": "69.9",
  "firma_barkod": "091986 "
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for-loop you need to **re-initialize** the `stoktbl` object

```
for(var satirx=1; satirx<rowCount; satirx++){
   stoktbl = {};
   //rest of the cpde
}
```

Otherwise, your `table` array will keep on using the same object at all the indexes.

Also, you need to use `push` method to add object to array

```
for(var satirx=1; satirx<rowCount; satirx++)
{
    stoktbl = {};
    stoktbl.firma_barkod=document.getElementById(satirx +"_"+"1").value;
    stoktbl.adet= document.getElementById(satirx +"_"+"5").value;
    stoktbl.birim_satis_fiyati= document.getElementById(satirx +"_"+"6").value;
    table.push( stoktbl );
}
```

This will ensure that first element of `table` array is not null.